# How Do I Make a Service Worker Compatible with Wildcard Subdomains?

Tags: javascript, json, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I have a fairly simple question. I have a manifest.json file for my new service worker that lists "start_url" as "https://example.com" and the scope is "/". That works great unless the URL has a subdomain. In that case I get several errors saying that the manifest start url is not valid, it has been ignored, and that the manifest has no matching service worker.

The service worker still works but I would like to eliminate these errors. I use wildcard subdomains for all listings categorized by geographic location (ex: https://city-state.example.com). That lets me feather out the categories on the other side of the domain name (ex: https://city-state.example.com/category/subcategory). Is there a way to use something like https://(*).example.com for the start url or scope to avoid this error?

Answer (score 2):

A service worker is scoped to a single origin and no higher in a file page than the level it is served from.
The rules are to provide security and prevent 3rd party scripts from attaching service workers to invade your site.

You will have to replicate your service worker on each origin. But honestly, unless the application is exactly the same you will want to customize the service worker logic to the specific application.